# How can I only allow merge request from one specific branch to another specific branch in GitLab?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-pipelines

In GitLab, I just wan to the merge requests from `sit -> uat -> master`.

How can I implement it by pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

You should be albe to use a combination of:

- [`rules:if`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#rulesif), as illustrated in [`workflow:rules`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#workflowrules)
- [Predefined variables reference](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html#predefined-variables-reference), like

  - `CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE`: How the pipeline was triggered
  - `CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME`: The target branch name of the merge request.
  - `CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME`: The source branch name of the merge request.

Something like:

```yaml
sit-to-uat:
  stage: build
  image: yourImage
  script:
    - # do something
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event" && 
           $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME =~ /^sit$/' && 
           $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME =~ /^uat$/'
      when: always
```